# Return Values from PHP to JSON/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

A friend of mine had given me this snippet for a js file that can be useful for me:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../CheckPerson.php",
    data: "{'lastName':'" + _lname + "','firstName':'" + _fname + "','middleName':'" + _mname + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var res = response.d;
        if (res == true) {
            jAlert('Patient Name already exists!', 'Error');
            return;
        }
        else { 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "../NewPerson.php",
                data: "{'lastName':'" + _lname + "','firstName':'" + _fname + "','middleName':'" + _mname + "','gender':'" + _gender + "','birthDate':'" + _bday + "','ssn':'" + _ssn + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var _id = response.d;
                    if (_id.length != 0) {
                        $('#patientName').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('#patientName').val(_lname + ", " + _fname + " " + _mname);
                        $('#patientId').val(_id[0].patientID);
                        $('#dateOfBirth').val(_bday);
                        $('#referringDoctor').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('#referringDoctor').focus();
                        $('#patientAge').val(_id[1]);
                        $('#ptLastName').val('');
                        $('#ptFirstName').val('');
                        $('#ptMiddleName').val('');
                        $('#ptGender').val('');
                        // $('input[name="birthdate"]').val(); // $('#ptBirthDate').val();
                        $('#ptSSN').val('');
                    }
                    // if (_id == true) {
                    // }
                    insertCallback(_id);
                    // $('#diagnosis tbody>tr:last').attr('dinfo', '_IEDiagnosis|' + _id);
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using PHP but I'm new to using JSON. Is there a way to return a `true` value for "response.d" in my PHP file:

```
success: function (response) {
    var _id = response.d;
}
```

Here's my logic but don't know the code to use:

```
$lastname = isset($_REQUEST['lastName'])?$_REQUEST['lastName']:'';
$firstname = isset($_REQUEST['firstName'])?$_REQUEST['firstName']:'';
$middlename = isset($_REQUEST['middleName'])?$_REQUEST['middleName']:'';
$response = array();
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("healthpal");

$query = "SELECT Lastname, Firstname, MiddleName FROM db_patients WHERE Lastname = '$lastname' || Firstname = '$firstname' || MiddleName = '$middlename'";

$qrytest = mysql_query($query);
if (isset($qrytest)) {
    //"response.d" will be true if the query return  not NULL
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. already made the code work.
my problem now is how to post my Json data in my php file.
something like:
$var = $_POST['jsondata1']; //the variable will have the value of 1 of the Json data

i'm trying json_decode(); and also 
isset($_REQUEST['lastName'])?$_REQUEST['lastName']:'';
but didn't work.
any help will really be appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
echo json_encode( array( 'd' => true ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the php json_encode function:

```
json_encode(array('response'=>'true')));
```

Comment: thanks. I appreciate your help. I already using it to return a true value for 'response.d'. in my php file and it works. but my real problem is that it does not work with the js snippet above. im using firebug to see what happen and it seems it had an error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct JSON string in your PHP file, some thing like this

```
     {"result":"true"}
```

this constructed JSON string should return as PHP response. In Javascript parse the JSON as,

```
var obj = eval(response)
if(obj.result == 'true'){
    //Do your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. My php file had already returning the value {"result":"true"} like you said. But when the JSON was parse in  the Javascript it seems nothing happens and an error returned on my FIREBUG console. hope you can also help me with this.